# Hide/Show Navigation

Tags: jquery, navigation, show-hide

I have a project that I borrowed some JavaScript from a lab that I did in class a year ago and I'm a little rusty so I can't figure out why it isn't working correctly. I made an example site so you can see how it's not working. It is located at [amykate.com/test](http://amykate.com/test) and the example files can be downloaded at [amykate.com/test.zip](http://amykate.com/test.zip).

I need it set up so that when you first navigate to the site there would be no content showing from the "main" div. This allows for the slideshow I'll have going in the background to be the main focus. Once you click on a link though, it should show the appropriate content from the associated div overtop of the slideshow. (I left all the slideshow stuff out for the example because it isn't necessary.) The problem I am having is that once you click on a link, you have to then refresh the page to actually see the content. Why is that? I wanted to be able to not have to refresh the page at all so that the slideshow can just continue in the background the whole time. Any suggestions?

Here is how the HTML structure is set up...

```
<nav id="hide-show-nav">
    <a href="#about">About</a> |
    <a href="#gallery">Gallery</a> |
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</nav>

<div id="main">

    <div id="about">
        <p>This is the about section.</p>
    </div> <!-- #about -->

    <div id="gallery">
        <p>This is the gallery section.</p>
    </div> <!-- #gallery -->

    <div id="contact">
        <p>This is the contact section.</p>
    </div> <!-- #contact -->

</div> <!-- #main -->
```

And the JavaScript goes like this...

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      oldonload();
      func();
    }
  }
}

function addEvent(element, type, handler)
{
    if (element.addEventListener)
        element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    else
    {
        if (!handler.$$guid) handler.$$guid = addEvent.guid++;
        if (!element.events) element.events = {};
        var handlers = element.events[type];
        if (!handlers)
        {
            handlers = element.events[type] = {};
            if (element['on' + type]) handlers[0] = element['on' + type];
            element['on' + type] = handleEvent;
        }

        handlers[handler.$$guid] = handler;
    }
}
addEvent.guid = 1;

addLoadEvent(init);


function init()
{
    findDest();

    //get reference to container element
    var holder = document.getElementById('main');

    //create ref to all divs inside of main
    var divs = holder.getElementsByTagName('DIV');
    var l = divs.length;

    //get reference to nav
    var nav = document.getElementById('hide-show-nav');

    //create ref to all links in nav
    var links = nav.getElementsByTagName('A');
    var numLinks = links.length;

    //loop over links add event listeners
    for(var j=0; j < numLinks; j++)
    {
        addEvent(links[j], 'click', showDiv);   
        addEvent(links[j], 'click', setStatus); 
    }
}


function showDiv(evt)
{
    //get reference to container element
    var holder = document.getElementById('main');

    //create ref to all divs inside of main
    var divs = holder.getElementsByTagName('DIV');
    var l = divs.length;

    //loop over divs and hide them all
    for(var i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        divs[i].className = 'hide'; 
    }

    //get reference to link click on
    var target = evt.target || window.event.srcElement;
    var destination = target.href;
    var divName = destination.split('#')[1];
    document.getElementById(divName).className = 'show';
}

function findDest()
{
    //get reference to container element
    var holder = document.getElementById('main');

    //create ref to all divs inside of main
    var divs = holder.getElementsByTagName('DIV');
    var l = divs.length;

    //loop over divs and hide them all
    for(var i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        divs[i].className = 'hide'; 
    }

    //get reference to link click on
    var destName = window.location.toString();
    var loc = destName.split('#')[1];   
    document.getElementById(loc).className = 'show';
}

function setStatus(evt)
{
    //get reference to link click on
    var target = evt.target || window.event.srcElement;

    //get reference to nav
    var nav = document.getElementById('hide-show-nav');

    //create ref to all links in nav
    var links = nav.getElementsByTagName('A');
    var numLinks = links.length;

    //loop over links add event listeners
    for(var j=0; j < numLinks; j++)
    {
        changeClassName('remove', links[j], 'statusOn');
    }

    //add status indication to link
    changeClassName('add', target, 'statusOn');

}
```

And this little bit of CSS...

```
.hide {
    display:none;
}

.show {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: nav id is different from what are you calling in getelementsbyid('nav')

Comment: Thanks. I fixed that, but that still didn't resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did finally figure this out a while ago and figured I'd post what I did incase anyone else comes across this.

```
$(function() {
    $('#main').addClass('hide');
});

$('body').on('click','nav a', function(e) {
    $('#main').removeClass('hide');
    $('#main').children().addClass('hide');
    $($(this).attr('href')).removeClass('hide');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Btw, I didn't figure this out on my own. I had to post my question a little differently and that's when I got my answer. Here's the link to the post where my answer came from. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168914/hide-div-until-link-is-selected

Answer (score 2):

Your 128 lines of javascript would like this in jQuery :

```
$(function() {
    $("#hide-show-nav​​​ a​").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $($(this).attr('href'), '#main').show().siblings().hide();
    })​​;​
})​​;​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/z27Qx/2/)

Comment: +1, I was just getting ready to answer the same thing. @blahblahAMYblah - if you're using jQuery, get rid of `addEvent` and `addLoadEvent`; you are using jQuery precisely so you do NOT have to use functions like those. Also, get Firebug!

Answer (score 0):

```
//get reference to nav
    var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
```

There is no element with id 'nav' . I think it should be 'hide-show-nav'.Check it once. Something like this..

```
//get reference to nav
    var nav = document.getElementById('hide-show-nav');
```

Comment: Okay, I fixed that, but that didn't seem to resolve the issue. Thanks for catching that though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jQuery which is very useful for that kind of situation ?
For what I see in your JS code, you're complicating your life a lot and this could be written in 5 lines of code :

```
$('body').on('click','#hide-show-nav a', function(e) {
    //hide all children div inside your main container
    $('#main').children().addClass('hide');
    //show only the one clicked
    $($(this).attr('href')).removeClass('hide');
    //prevent the default behaviour of the anchor
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

if you want a special div inside your main shown by default, then put your "hide" class on the other ones.

Comment: This is perfect! How can I tell it to have all the divs hidden when you first open the page though? It works at toggling the divs right now, but when it first opens, all of them show when I want none of them to.

Comment: just add a "hide" class on each divs